# JQuery Flot working in IE6 but not IE8

Tags: jquery, flot

I have two pages that use the flot jquery plugin, and they both work great in most browsers, and even in IE6. The problem is that the canvas portion of the graph doesn't show up in IE8 and possibly IE7. The key is there, and the axis labels are there, but not the graph itself.

http://www.statisticshowto.com/calculators/interquartile-range-calculator/

http://www.statisticshowto.com/calculators/binomial-distribution-calculator/

I can't find anything on google that would explain the discrepancy.

Edit:

This may not be a Flot thing after all. I'm using conditional comments in my code in order to include an IE fix in the javascript. It appears as though the conditional is ignored in IE8 standards mode. Is there a different workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using flot 0.4 (from the year 2007, time before IE8!), latest version of flot is 0.6. Since you're using packed version of excanvas I can't verify its version but it may be worth it to try to update that one too.

Comment: Nowadays the latest version of flot is 0.7. The lib can be found from here: http://code.google.com/p/flot/